# VB.NET Console Application | Display Factorial with User Entered Number

Tags: vb.net, loops, optimization

My code works fine but needs some optimizing without any additional variables or loops. 
The output should look like: 5 X 4 X 3 X 2 X 1 = 120

```
Private Sub FactorialCalculation()

    Dim Number, Factorial As Integer

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number")
    Number = CInt(Console.ReadLine)
    Factorial = 1

    Console.WriteLine("Your number is " & Number)

    If Number > 0 Then
        Console.Write(Number & " X ")
        For Count As Integer = 1 To Number
            If (Number - Count) > 0 And (Number - Count) <> 1 Then
                Factorial *= Count
                Console.Write("{0} X ", Number - Count)
            ElseIf (Number - Count) = 0 Then
                Factorial *= Count
            ElseIf (Number - Count) = 1 Then
                Factorial *= Count
                Console.Write(Number - Count)
            End If

        Next
        Console.WriteLine(" = {0}", Factorial)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a positive number greater than 0")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: perhaps this question would be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ??

Answer (score 1):

Complete example similar to yours. The point is to use a function. I chose recursion

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number")
    Dim number As Long
    If Long.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, number) AndAlso number >= 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Your number is " & number)
        Try
            Console.WriteLine("{0} factorial = {1}", number, fact(number))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a positive number greater than 0")
    End If
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Private Function fact(ByVal number As Long) As Long
    Return If(number = 0, 1, number * fact(number - 1))
End Function
```

Could also restrict to numbers <= 20 since Int64 can't seem to hold fact 21 or more.